# Column of keyboard keys not working

Tags: capacitor, repair, keyboard

So every key that is on this trace is not working. Is C25 the culprit? It is a mechanical keyboard and there is continuity between all of the keys on the trace, and they all go to this jumbled mess of stuff I don't understand. The keys stopped working after I mistakenly dunked my keyboard in multipurpose cleaner for several days. If it isn't C25, does anything in the vicinity look particularly suspect?

[image: The area in question]

Comment: SMD capacitors are quite robust: try debugging that column...how does it differ from other columns? These column-rows are scanned quickly by that chip, so an oscilloscope may be needed for troubleshooting. Sometimes a column driver in that chip can fail, but in your case, circuit board traces are at risk. Have you cleaned liquid all up? Have you dried it very thoroughly?

Comment: why are you not considering the damaged area on the board as the primary suspect?

Comment: What makes you suspect C25? It doesn't look odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

The trace near the arrow (which may connect to C25) appears to be broken/corroded.  You need to carefully solder a jumper wire across the trace break.

To say for certain you need a photo taken at an angle with lighting that makes it easier to see the traces near the arrow. At present the flash reflection obscures the key area.

Comment: Agree that the trace appears to be damaged, with the solder resist removed and thus exposing the underlying copper. The trace does appear to connect to ``C25``, but from the picture can't determine if ``C25`` is damaged or not.